# How can I use Vuex modules getters with composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vuejs3

This is my Vuex getter:

```
const getters = {
  getMovieById: state => id => {
    debugger;
    return state.movies.find(movie => movie.id === id);
  }
};
```

I am importing the module in my component:

```
import movieMod from "../store/modules/movies";
```

I am storing the returned value of the getter in my reactive object:

```
 movie = movieMod.getters.getMovieById(parseInt(props.id));
```

This is returning me the following function:

```
(id) {
  debugger;
  return state.movies.find(function (movie) {
    return movie.id === id;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
movie = movieMod.getters.getMovieById(state)(parseInt(props.id)
```

`getMovieById` is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function), which is a function that returns a function. In your case, you are not executing the returned function.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my approach was wrong. I was supposed to use the hook from the composition API rather than importing the module.

```
import { useStore } from "vuex";

setup(props) {
  const store = useStore();
  return {
    movie: computed(() => store.getters.getMovieById(parseInt(props.id)))
  };
}
```